# In a microservices based architecture how would i go about database access?

Tags: database, hibernate, microservices

I am trying to push myself into developing a set of microservices for a personal project that will essentially:

Use elastic search
Poll various data stores
place data and read data from a data store
Expose a rest api to users

for the purposes of this example lets say I had a bookings MS and a Sales MS

The first thing that occurred to me was how to handle data storage.

1. Should each MS have its own data store?
2. Should I introduce a Persistence MS which handles all data from all other micro services (seems odd to do this).
3. Should each MS share a database but handle its own transactions.

In the case where you have each service handling its own persistence will that not significantly bloat a micro service to the point where you have a lot of boilerplate code and a large overall footprint of libraries (as an example hibernate would be a required library across every project and it seems terrible to have every MS having to load the same set of libraries).

So I suppose the overriding question is what is the accepted methodology for managing database connectivity across a micro service architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is quite simple:

- Don't try to build a distributed monolith: don't build a persistance layer as a microservice.
- Don't try to perform distributed transaction and try to have a functional approach by having a domain bound service.
- You will have to include Hibernate in several microservices. This is a tradeoff you will have to accept.